# Trouble with pset3 game of fifteen

Tags: c, cs50

My functions (init,draw,move and win) are not working properly. Can anyone shed some light on where I am going wrong?

- init - should initialer the board and swap 1 and 2.
- draw - should draw the current state of the board.
- move - should move the tile if not illegal move.
- win - should check the board if its in descending order.

---

```
/**
 * fifteen.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 3
 *
 * Implements Game of Fifteen (generalized to d x d).
 *
 * Usage: fifteen d
 *
 * whereby the board's dimensions are to be d x d,
 * where d must be in [DIM_MIN,DIM_MAX]
 *
 * Note that usleep is obsolete, but it offers more granularity than
 * sleep and is simpler to use than nanosleep; `man usleep` for more.
 */
#
define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

# include < cs50.h > #include < stdio.h > #include < string.h > #include <
    stdlib.h > #include < unistd.h >

    // constants
    #define DIM_MIN 3# define DIM_MAX 9

// board
int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];

// dimensions
int d;

// prototypes
void clear(void);
void greet(void);
void init(void);
void draw(void);
bool move(int tile);
bool won(void);
void metrytoexchange(int * a, int * b);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: fifteen d\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // ensure valid dimensions
    d = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (d < DIM_MIN || d > DIM_MAX) {
        printf("Board must be between %i x %i and %i x %i, inclusive.\n",
            DIM_MIN, DIM_MIN, DIM_MAX, DIM_MAX);
        return 2;
    }

    // open log
    FILE * file = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return 3;
    }

    // greet user with instructions
    greet();

    // initialize the board
    init();

    // accept moves until game is won
    while (true) {
        // clear the screen
        clear();

        // draw the current state of the board
        draw();

        // log the current state of the board (for testing)
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
                fprintf(file, "%i", board[i][j]);
                if (j < d - 1) {
                    fprintf(file, "|");
                }
            }
            fprintf(file, "\n");
        }
        fflush(file);

        // check for win
        if (won()) {
            printf("ftw!\n");
            break;
        }

        // prompt for move
        printf("Tile to move: ");
        int tile = GetInt();

        // quit if user inputs 0 (for testing)
        if (tile == 0) {
            break;
        }

        // log move (for testing)
        fprintf(file, "%i\n", tile);
        fflush(file);

        // move if possible, else report illegality
        if (!move(tile)) {
            printf("\nIllegal move.\n");
            usleep(500000);
        }

        // sleep thread for animation's sake
        usleep(500000);
    }

    // close log
    fclose(file);

    // success
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Clears screen using ANSI escape sequences.
 */
void clear(void) {
    printf("\033[2J");
    printf("\033[%d;%dH", 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Greets player.
 */
void greet(void) {
    clear();
    printf("WELCOME TO GAME OF FIFTEEN\n");
    usleep(2000000);
}

/**
 * Initializes the game's board with tiles numbered 1 through d*d - 1
 * (i.e., fills 2D array with values but does not actually print them).  
 */
void init(void) {
    // TODO
    int i, j;
    int k = d * d - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            board[i][j] = k--;
            if (k % 2 != 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                if ((board[i][j] == 2) && (board[i][j - 1] == 1))
                    metrytoexchange( & board[i][j], & board[i][j - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Prints the board in its current state.
 */
void draw(void) { // TODO
    int k = d * d - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            board[i][j] = k--;
            if (board[i][j] == 0) {
                printf("_");
            } else
                printf("%d \t", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void metrytoexchange(int * a, int * b) {
    int temp = * a; *
    a = * b; *
    b = temp;
}

/**
 * If tile borders empty space, moves tile and returns true, else
 * returns false. 
 */
bool move(int tile) {
    int k = d * d - 1;
    int blank_space = 0;
    //dont go beyond the grid
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {

            if (tile < k && tile > 0 && tile == board[i][j]) {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
            //iterate to check the position of of blank tile;left to right up and down if not return false
            if (board[i - 1][j] != blank_space || board[i][j - 1] !=
                blank_space || board[i + 1][j] != blank_space || board[i][j +
                    1
                ] != blank_space) {
                return false;
            }
            //else swap tile with blank_space
            else {
                metrytoexchange( & tile, & blank_space);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns true if game is won (i.e., board is in winning configuration), 
 * else false.
 */
bool won(void) {
    // TODO
    // creat a variable that increases as the loop condition increases.let it start from 1 increasing
    int win_board[d][d];
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
            if (win_board[i][j] == board[i][j]) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your init inner loop breaks after the1st or 2nd loop. `if(k%2!=0) break`.
`if((board[i][j]==2) && (board[i][j-1]==1))` will never happen, becaus you fill the board with `k--` and if the current `board[i][j]==2` there can no entry be 1.

Comment: In draw() you are filling the board again like init. You often access board with i-1 or j-1 which may result in board[-1].

Comment: In won() you declare win_board and use it in compares without initializing.
In won() the first compare (i==0 and j==0) returns true or false.

Comment: The indent is horrible to find the executing code.

Comment: There is a CS50x Q & A site that will probably be able to help you better! http://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Holger i made the corrections all seems to work fine except move, it changes the_ to 95.hints please?https://gist.github.com/a6cbbc29a9f839d2ebc6865e2cd0c65c

Comment: As I told, move() accesses board with [i-1] or [j-1]. But i and j maybe 0 at that time.

Comment: @Holger do you mean i will go off the the grid? if so i thought am covered with if statment......what is your suggestion?

Comment: You should change `if(board[i-1][j]==blank_space)` to `if(i>0 && board[i-1][j]==blank_space)`. Same with `j-1`. And `if(board[i+1][j]==blank_space)` to `if((i+1)<d && board[i+1][j]==blank_space)`. Same with `j+1`. You fill the board beginning with d*d-1. So the last entry `[d-1][d-1]` will get the value 0. If you look for the tiles 2 and 1 in `if(board[3][1]==2 && board[3][2]==1)` it should be `if(board[d-1][d-3]==2 && board[d-1][d-2]==1)`. But only if d>=3.